# Foreach for courses sections and lessons

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to count current course sections and then that section lessons and durability.
this is my foreach

```
<div class="card-content-box">
            @foreach($courses as $c)
            <p class="card-content-box__quantity">
            @foreach($c->sections as $s)
                <span class="card-content-box__quantity-time">
                    {{ $s->count('id') }} section
                </span>
                @endforeach
                @foreach($s->lessons as $l)
                <span class="card-content-box__quantity-time">
                    {{ $l->count('id') }} lesson
                </span>
                <span class="card-content-box__quantity-lecture">
                    {{ $l->count('durability') }} lesson durability
                </span>
                @endforeach
            </p>
            @endforeach
        </div>
```

and it's coming very wired.
I think it's my foreach fault
i'm getting

30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability

30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability

30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  30 section  15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability

15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability

15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability

15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability

15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability

15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability

15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability

15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability 15 lesson  15 lesson durability

Comment: What is the issue here ? what do you expect the output would be ?  `count current course sections and then that section lessons and durability` which section ? you have a count of sections not a single section to count its lessons. Figure out how you want the final output to look like first.

Comment: this current course haves 10 sections  so it's must count in sections table course_id then this section having 5 lessons so in lessons table it must count section_id and durability must be 45 min  so in final it must be 10 sections  5 lessons 45 durability

Comment: again you said "this section" wich one is it ? the course have 10 sections !? do you mean 1 course 10 sections 50 lessons and 2250 durability  like the sum of all for that course (if each section has 5 lessons then 1 course has 50 lessons through 10 sections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the total count for each course

You need these relations in place:

- Lesson -> section() (belongsTo)
- Section -> course() (belongsTo)

```
<div class="card-content-box">
    @foreach($courses as $course)
        <p class="card-content-box__quantity">
            <span class="card-content-box__quantity-time">
                {{ $course->sections()->count() }} section
            </span>
            <span class="card-content-box__quantity-time">
                {{ Lesson::whereHas('section.course', function($cq) use ($course) {$cq->where('id', $course->id);})->count() }} lesson
            </span>
            <span class="card-content-box__quantity-lecture">
                {{ Lesson::whereHas('section.course', function($cq) use ($course) {$cq->where('id', $course->id);})->sum('durability') }} lesson durability
            </span>

        </p>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

no need for loops other than the course one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="card-content-box">
    @foreach($courses as $c)
        <p class="card-content-box__quantity">
            @foreach($c->sections as $s)
                <span class="card-content-box__quantity-time">
                    {{ $s->count('id') }} section
                </span>
                @foreach($s->lessons as $l)
                    <span class="card-content-box__quantity-time">
                    {{ $l->count('id') }} lesson
                </span>
                    <span class="card-content-box__quantity-lecture">
                    {{ $l->count('durability') }} lesson durability
                </span>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        </p>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

this one should work. in you code, you used `$s->lessons as $l` outside the loops of sections. so, `$s` was actually working with the last object.